# Fix .htaccess error - RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have this error in error.log caused by `.htaccess`:

```
AH00665: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

What does it say? How to fix it?

This is `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

According the error.log, line 11 is cause of the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
```

Comment: Just remove `[NC]` from this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]`

Comment: OK, it worked, tnx @anubhava What the `[NC]` does?

Comment: `NC` is for ignore case, however for `-f` it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @anubhava suggestion I have removed `[NC]` from the line 11 and the error disappeared.